# Greens theorem over a trapezoid

Tags: greens-theorem

[image]

This is the solution to a problem on greens theorem bounded by a trapezoid. I am stuck on the third last equality sign. I suspect it has to do with symmetry of the domain but can not see how it has been applied. Appreciate it if someone could clarify it for me.

Comment: You can simplify the question down to this: Why does $\iint_T y\,dA=0$? (You're right to think symmetry...)

Comment: Facepalm!! Got it. Thank you Semiclassical

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$
\int \int _T (3+2y)dA=\int \int _T 3dA+\int \int _T 2ydA
$$

and,

$$
\int \int _T 2ydA=\int_0^1dx\int_{-2+x}^{2-x}2y dy=\int_0^1 [(2-x)^2-(x-2)^2]dx=0
$$